# Kusto streaming Ingestion throws exception

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-explorer

I'm using Azure functions to ingest data from event hub to ADX cluster. Below is the code

```cs
[FunctionName("Ingestion")]
public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("eh-test", Connection = "ehconnection")] EventData[] events,
[Kusto(Database: "testdb",
TableName = "testTable", 
Connection = "KustoConnectionString",
ManagedServiceIdentity = "system")] IAsyncCollector<Model> output, ILogger log)
{
    foreach (EventData eventData in events)
    {
        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.EventBody.ToArray());
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(data);
        await output.AddAsync(obj);
    }
}
```

The Model objects are added correctly. Few records are ingested successfully. However, few records failed throwing exception

```
innermostMessage
{
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Request is invalid and cannot be executed.",
"@type": "Kusto.DataNode.Exceptions.StreamingIngestionRequestException",
"@message": "Bad streaming ingestion request to testdb.testTable : RS engine operation 'CreateRowStoreValueFromStream' returned unknown Code=80131500. RowStoreName='', RowStoreKey=, DatabaseName='testdb', TableName='testTable'
}
}
```

All the objects are deserialized without errors. How could this happen only for few records ?

Model

```
public class Model
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public object? Details { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; } 
    public bool flag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the Model Class

Comment: Added the model.

Comment: The ADX table has more fields than in the model. But I'm using only the required fields in the model. I hope that wouldn't be an issue as few records gets ingested successfully

Comment: What's the cluster name and what is the approximate time of the failure?

Comment: @DxG please share the sample records which are being inserted successfully and which are not? Also share the the connection string format which you are using for `KustoConnectionString`